# How Call Method<T> Generic

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a problem on having called a generic method, I have searched very much and do not find a solution, this one is my mistake.
And I do not have knowledge of I am doing badly,

> The type arguments for method 'FormGasolineUserControl.loadList<T>(list<T>,string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. try specifying the type arguments expliciy.

this is my code:

This chunk of code where I obtain the error

```
private void loadDataForm()
{
    try
    {               
        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;    
        // Call Services WPF
        var QueryBD = services.LoadDataFormGasoline(1, (int)ETax.Gasoline);     
        if (QueryBD.Company != null)
        {
            day.Value = dateNow.Day.ToString();
            month.Value = dateNow.Month.ToString();
            year.Value = dateNow.Year.ToString();
            anioGravable.Value = dateNow.Year.ToString();
            peridoGravable.Value = PeriodoGravable(dateNow).ToString(); 

            //Error call Method
            loadList( QueryBD.QualityDeclarate, QualityDeclarate.Name.ToString()); 
            loadList( QueryBD.TypeDeclarate, TypeDeclarate.Name.ToString());            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }

}
```

And this one is the method:

```
public void loadlist<T>(List<T> lista,string nameControl)
{           
    try
    {       
        switch (nameControl)
        {  
            case "TypeDeclarate":
                TypeDeclarate.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select..."));
                foreach (var name in lista)
                {
                    TypeDeclarate.Items.Add(new ListItem(name.ToString()));
                }
            break;
            case "QualityDeclarate":
                QualityDeclarate.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select..."));
                foreach (var name in lista)
                {
                    QualityDeclarate.Items.Add(new ListItem(name.ToString()));
                }
            break;                   
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

My principal aim is to be able to load the usercontrol dynamicamente by means of lists consulted in database.
help me plis...

Comment: It sounds like you actually want two overloaded methods.

Comment: @Dawid It is in the moment to call to the method loadlist<T>()

Comment: So what type *is* `QueryBD.QualityDeclarate`? Is it a `List<>` of something? In your method, `IEnumerable>object>` should be enough, you don't need a generic. You should probably have two distinct methods though.

Comment: What are the types of `QueryBD.QualityDeclarate` and `QueryBD.TypeDeclarate`?

Comment: QueryBD.QualityDeclarate and QueryBD.TypeDeclarate They are lists of models created for my

Comment: You need to pass List of generic params as first argument

Comment: @nvoigt thanks you were of great help

Comment: Why do you use generic version if you never using `T`?

Comment: @sTrenat I am new in this and I thought that it was the best way of doing it.

Comment: You could jsut create method `void loadlist(IList lista,string nameControl)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176816/discussion-between-jonathan-burgos-gio-and-strenat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code could be improved in a great many ways.

- It should not be generic.
- It could be refactored into smaller methods that are more clear.
- The naming conventions do not follow C# conventions.
- It takes a list but only enumerates the elements
- It really operates on sequences of strings.
- The try-catch is useless.

Let's fix it.

```
private void AddItemsToCollection(IEnumerable<string> names, IList<ListItem> items) 
{
  items.Add(new ListItem("Select..."));
  foreach (var name in names)
    items.Add(new ListItem(name));
}
```

See how simple that is?  **Make simple methods that do one thing well.** Now we use that helper to make other simple methods:

```
private void AddItemsToCollection(IEnumerable names, IList<ListItem> items) 
{
  AddItemsToCollection(names.Cast<object>().Select(n => n.ToString(), items);
}
```

Again, super simple. One line. Let's make more one-liners:

```
public void AddTypeDeclarateItems(IEnumerable names)
{
  AddItemsToCollection(names, TypeDeclarate.Items);
}
```

SO EASY.  Do it again.

```
public void AddQualityDeclarateItems(IEnumerable names)
{
  AddItemsToCollection(names, QualityDeclarate.Items);
}
```

And now our method is simple:

```
public void AddItemsToCollection(IEnumerable names, string control)
{           
  switch (control)
  {  
    case "TypeDeclarate":
      AddTypeDeclarateItems(names);
      break;
    case "QualityDeclarate":
      AddQualityDeclarateItems(names);
      break;
  }
}
```

Your code will get easier to understand, easier to make correct, easier to debug, if you simplify it so that every method does *one thing*.

Alternative solution: move the switch into a helper:

```
IList<ListItem> GetItems(string control)
{
  switch (control)
  {  
    case "TypeDeclarate":
      return TypeDeclarate.Items;
    case "QualityDeclarate":
      return QualityDeclarate.Items;       
  }
  throw new SomeException(...);
}
```

And now our method is:

```
public void AddItemsToCollection(IEnumerable names, string control)
{           
  AddItemsToCollection(names, GetItems(control));
}
```

Again, see what happens when you make every method do *one thing*?  Every method gets *really easy to understand*, and highly likely to be correct.

Comment: Is there a non-pedagogical reason for the helper methods to use `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<object>`?

Comment: @Brian: Good point; I should have clarified that. It's (1) because all we need is IEnumerable in order to `ToString` a thing; a method should accept the most general thing it needs. (Speaking of which, `IList<T>` is unnecessarily specific!)  And (2) because I don't know if the collections are collections of value types. An `IEnumerable<S>` for some struct type `S` cannot be converted to `IEnumerable<object>` without a `Cast`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  My tendency is to treat `IEnumerable` as a legacy interface from pre-generic .Net.  Hence, I tend to ignore #1 and treat #2 as a rare scenario.

Comment: @Brian: Another thing that I might have mentioned was that this *is* a good case for generics. You could write a generic helper method that takes `IEnumerable<T>`, extracts the `T`, and then calls `ToString` without incurring a boxing penalty. But that's maybe not an optimization that is worth caring about.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to call this method:

```
...
loadlist<string>(QueryBD.myListOfStrings, "nameControl");
loadlist<int>(QueryBD.myListOfInts,"nameControl");
...
```

But, I guess that maybe the problem is inside the class that contains the method 
`void loadlist<T>(List<T> lista,string nameControl)`.

Aswer this question: What is T? I mean, in a class declaration we have many possibilities.

We can set T argument like a class: `public MyClass<T> where T : class`; 
A struct: `public MyClass<T> where T : struct`; A class that has a public constructor `public MyClass<T> where T : new()`,...

See all possibilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

So, let's imagine that T is a class that must implements an interface and you're passing a class that doesn't implement it, so you'll not have success.